# Rust use different variable value for Cargo profile

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

This is surprisingly hard to find in the documentation. I want to use a different `base_url` for my API endpoint for every Cargo profile. So, `—-profile=debug` will use https://localhost:3000, and `—-profile=release` will use https://api.cooldomain.io/ or something like that.

Any pointers?

Comment: You maybe will find useful information on https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html

Comment: config.toml allows you to fill up variables for each profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your `base_url` using `#[cfg(debug_assertions)]` for debug profiles and using `#[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]` for non debug profiles.

For example like this

```
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
const BASE_URL:&'static str = "http://localhost:3000";

#[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
const BASE_URL:&'static str = "https://api.cooldomain.io/";

fn main() {
    println!("{}",BASE_URL);
}
```

You can read more about debug_assertions [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#debug_assertions)